# Using Where clause for DateTime field using a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am trying to return records for users based on their telephone numbers as well as a restriction to the `PolicyEnd` Field (DateTime Format) to return only those that are greater than or equal to 2022. However, I keep on running into several errors:

1. **&& DateTime.ParseExact(s: ti0.Outer.Inner.PolicyEnd,format: "yyy-MM-dd",provider: __InvariantCulture_0) > DateTime.Now)' could not be translated.**

   ```
           var QUERY = from client in _ipacontext.Inclients
                   join policy in _ipacontext.Inpolicies on client.ClientId equals policy.AccountNo
                   join types in _ipacontext.InpolicyTypes on policy.PolicyType equals types.TypeId
                   where client.Telephone2 == "0000000" && DateTime.ParseExact(policy.PolicyEnd, "yyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > 2022
   ```

I have also tried this below but in vain :

```
where client.Telephone2 == "000000"  &&  Convert.ToDateTime(policy.PolicyEnd).Year >=2022
```

An example of the Date Format is as below:

`2022-08-31 00:00:00.000`

Any help on other workarounds?

Comment: The format is wrong you have `"yyy-MM-dd"` should be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Comment: You forgot to mention which library you're using to translate the Linq into SQL. That provider probably has custom utilities for Dates.

Comment: In addition, why are you parsing `policy.PolicyEnd` _to_ a DateTime? Are you storing your date _as a string_ in the database, which is a huge problem itself?

Comment: You say "PolicyEnd Field (DateTime Format)", but then show code parsing it. What is the *data type* of that column in the database? If it's text, what is the format? You show code that tries to parse it as `yyy-MM-dd` [sic: it should probably be 4 y's?], can't you them simply say `policyEnd >= "2022"` ? (and please, PLEASE don't store dates as text in the database!)

Comment: @gunr2171 ```policy.PolicyEnd``` is stored as DateTime in the database. However, I want to perform a query as such ``` policy.PolicyEnd > 2022``` yet ">" operands are not allowed for DateTime data types

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I would like the final query as ```where client.Telephone2 == "000000" && policy.PolicyEnd > 2022 ``` But as mentioned earlier, this won't work due to the operands restrictions on ">"

Comment: @Nickson dates have no format, they're binary values (except in SQLite). There's no `DateTime Format`. If you need to use `DateTime.Parse` it means you have a string field. That's a critical design bug that needs to be fixed *first*. You don't even know what's in there, as the type can allow any string in any format. Replace that with the appropriate type, eg `date` or `datetime`. Once that's fixed, you can compare date fields and `DateTime` objects directly.

Comment: @Nickson what database are you using? You should be able to map date fields to `DateTime` properties even with SQLite. To find records in 2022 all you'd need is `policy.PolicyEnd >= new DateTime(2023,1,1)`. This would result in a query that takes advantage of indexes covering `PolicyEnd` and only touch matching rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos MS SQL Server

Comment: In that case there's absolutely no reason to store dates as strings. The table field `PolicyEnd` should be either `date` or `datetime2`. The property type should be `DateTime`

Comment: @Nickson *"policy.PolicyEnd is stored as DateTime in the database"* Then simply use `Year` property for the desired condition, e.g. `policy.PolicyEnd.Year > 2022)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your db table column format datetime, just try to use function

```
var dt = new DateTime(2022,01,01);
....

 &&    EF.Functions.DateDiffYear(policy.PolicyEnd, dt) >= 0
```

or since you are checking only year you can try to use the whole data, sometimes it works

```
var dt =  new DateTime(2021, 12, 31).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
...

 &&  policy.PolicyEnd > dt
```

Comment: This would force a full table scan.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am sorry but it has &&  and OP variant will force full table  scan if it is not indexed.  And as I always tell pls post your suggestion how to do this if you have something else except to critisize. Better this than nothing.

Comment: I'm not criticizing. This is a bug, and won't even work if `PolicyEnd` isn't a DateTime. It's *easy* to fix this by calculating the date in advance instead of getting the database to calculate the difference `policy.PolicyEnd >=new DateTime(2023,1,1)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP told you policy.PolicyEnd is stored as DateTime in the database and it is an Sql Server.

Comment: In which case this answer should change to `policy.PolicyEnd >= new DateTime(2023,1,1)`. Why fix one bug only to introduce another? `&&` won't cause a full table scan on *policies*, even if `Client.Telephone2` isn't indexed. SQL Server may decide there are so few future policies it can start with a seek there and only then join with Client

Comment: Still suggesting `DateDiffYear` instead of simply `.Year` property sounds strange.

Comment: @IvanStoev what would `.Year` be translated to? If it is `DATEPART(d,PolicyEnd) > 2022` the problem remains

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi Ivan, happy to see you again. I don't know why .Year is not working,  I think it is question for EF team. But DateDiffYear  was especially created for EF and I believe that a team is smart enough to optimaze how it works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Almost sure `DATEPART(y, ...)` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Hi @Serge, Glad to see you again too. `Year`, `Month` etc. definitely works (is translated) for SqlServer.

Comment: @Serge `DateDiffYear` is [documented to map to `DATEDIFF(year, @startDate, @endDate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffyear?view=efcore-6.0). The *optimized* version is to detect this is used in a comparison, calculate a new cutoff date and essentially replace `DateDiffYear` with `field >= @newCutoff` or whatever operator is appropriate

Comment: @Charlieface I am sorry but I am sick from all this comments. What is the matter with people? Everybody selects the algorithm he likes. But I updated my answer in order to stop comments.

Answer (score 3):

Dates have no format, they're binary types in all databases (except SQLite). SQL Server has `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, `time` and the legacy `datetime` for storing dates and time-of-day. Storing dates as strings in a string field is a *critical* bug that *must* be fixed. There's no way to control what goes into a string field, which means it's quite easy for garbage or strings with the wrong format to end up in the database.

Trying to parse such strings will result in bad performance and increased blocking even if indexes are used. Indexes are built using the stored values, not function results. Trying to parse `PolicyEnd` and filter by a specific date would have to scan the entire table, parse the values and only then decide which values to include. It will take Shared locks on the entire table while doing so, which would block any UPDATE or DELETE calls that tried to run at the same time, even if they were outside the date range.

If the field uses a date type, the `PolicyEnd` property should be a `DateTime`. In that casefiltering to find all dates after 2022 would be just :

```
var fromDate=new DateTime(2023,1,1);

var query = ....
            where client.Telephone2 == "000000"  
                  && policy.PolicyEnd >=fromDate
```

This will result in a parameterized query that can use any indexes covering `PolicyEnd` to only touch policy rows whose `PolicyEnd` value matches the criteria.

The JOINs aren't necessary either. It's EF's job to generate the JOINs from the relations between entities. A `Client` should have a `Policies` collection. A `Policy` should have a `PolicyType`. A LINQ query that returns clients without a second phone whose policies end in the future should be :

```
var clients=from client in _context.Clients
            from policy in client.Policies
            where client.Telephone2 == "000000"  
                  && policy.PolicyEnd >=fromDate
            select ...;
```

Comment: Yup, this looks better.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have some 10M row tables with 3 years of data, so date queries are a ... sensitive issue. I even dropped `cast(EntryTime as date)` once I realized the problems it causes.

Comment: I know I usually argue against some of your comments, but in this case I'm actually agreeing/supporting your point/answer :-)